# Save last value in the variable and display

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, variables

I have a problem in my program its function is to display on the screen how much ram the process is consuming the time and display the peak memory usage ram, so that my problem is when I close the process, the program stop display the peak memory ram.

Here the part of the code that displays the peak ram:

```
public string vmax()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName(label92.Text);
    double avvv = 0;
    string abi = null;

    try
    {
        if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
            {
                String physicalMem = p.PeakWorkingSet64.ToString();
                abi = physicalMem;
            }
        }

        avvv = double.Parse(abi);
        avvv = avvv * 0.001 / 1024;

        return avvv + " K";
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label90.Text = vmax();
}
```

With the process of open calculator:

[image]

With the process of the closed calculator:

[image]

I wanted even when I closed the process he kept showing the last value recorded at the peak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the vmax function the current text value of your label and return it if the process is no more listed between the active processes

```
public string vmax(string prevValue)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName(label92.Text);
        if(ieProcs.Length == 0)
             return prevValue;
        ...
     }
     catch
     {
         return prevValue;
     }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label90.Text = vmax(label90.Text);
}
```

Said that I should say also that all of your string conversions are a bit confusing. PeakWorkingSet64 returns a long and there is no need to convert it to a string and then execute a parse of the same string to execute some calculation. Just use the long variable in your calculus and convert the result to a string just before returning from the vmax function

Comment: Thank you Steve worked! And also thank you for your tips, I am very beginner yet!